# Error in image upload using PHP GD Library

Tags: php, image, forms, upload, gd

I am not an PHP expert but i was trying to upload an image file using GD library but my code is showing error. Then i tried to echo the output but it is not showing the temporary location of the image file.

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['upload_btn'])){
$filename = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
list($w,$h)= getimagesize($filename);
$imgString = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
echo "Temp = $imgString <br>";
echo "Name = $filename <br>";
echo "Width = $w <br>";
echo "Height = $h";
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="_self" >
<input type="file" id="upload" name="file_upload" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload_btn" />
</form>
```

The output of the above code is as follows:

> Temp = 
>  Name = image1.jpg 
>  Width = 4440 
>  Height = 3294

Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Enable error reporting and try to dump out the contents of your `$_FILES` array ie `print_r($_FILES);`. Is the dimensions of the image correct?

Comment: You can also check the `error` of the upload to try to figure out what's not working `if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] != 0) { // some error occurred }`. You can checkout this page for a list of error codes: [File Upload Errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks a lot. This help will help me. I am updating the code and hopefully my problem will be solved.

Comment: What did you change, what kind of error code did you get? It's important that you tell us how you solved it since this can help others with the same kind of problem in the future.

Comment: upload_max_filesize is 2M so i change it to 12M in php.ini file and magic happens!!

Answer (score 2):

`$_FILES['file_upload']['name']` is just the name of the file. Which is actually not avaible on the server. unless you move the temp_file with the help of `move_uploaded_file()` method. You have to use `$_FILES['tmp_name']` which is actually the uploaded file.

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['upload_btn'])){
    $filename = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    $imgString = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    list($w,$h)= getimagesize($imgString);

    echo "Temp = $imgString <br>";
    echo "Name = $filename <br>";
    echo "Width = $w <br>";
    echo "Height = $h";
    }
    ?>
```

This was the case only if the file upload was successful. If the upload is not successful it will raise an error and it will be an error number which can be accessed from

```
$_FILES['file_upload']['error']
```

If it is 0 then your upload was successful. Otherwise the upload is failed. Then you will not get a result in  `$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']`

Comment: If you had **read** the OP you would have noticed that this is the actual problem. He's saying that `tmp_name` returns nothing. Still you are correct when it comes to what he will be using in the call to `getimagesize()`

Comment: but i am using localhost and also this problem is not with all the images. some files show temp = C:\wamp\tmp\phpFA82.tmp . so why some images show error and some don't?

Comment: @Abhimanu - Have a look at my comments above. Check if you get an error set in `$_FILES['file_upload']['error']` and if that's the case what kind of error code it is.